# NullPointer Exception on setAdapter()

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

This is my first android app and all i'm trying to do is basically create a list with some sample data. I get the "Unfortunately Sunshine has stopped" error on my phone when i run it.

If i remove this line of code, the app runs -

```
lstview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
```

Also When i remove this line of code and run the app i get a calendar of all years but i have not used a calendar anywhere in my code! Any idea why this happens?

Here is my MainActivity.java -

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            String[] forecastArray;
            forecastArray = new String[]{
                    "Today - Sunny 88/63",
                    "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                    "Thursday",
                    "Friday",
                    "Saturday",
                    "Sunday"
            };

            List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

            mForecastAdapter = new
                    ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    weekForecast);
            ListView lstview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            lstview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;

        }
    }
}
```

list_item_forecast.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
    >

</TextView>
```

fragment_main.xml -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prashanth.sunshine" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is a really simple program and i have looked everywhere and none of the solutions seem to work. So -

1. Why do i get an infinite calendar on my app when i remove this line of code?

   lstview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
2. Why does the app not run with that line?

BTW here is the logcat -

```
06-17 11:34:32.121  32380-32380/com.example.prashanth.sunshine I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1689948 time:428069386
06-17 11:36:28.478      641-641/com.example.prashanth.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-17 11:36:28.479      641-641/com.example.prashanth.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prashanth.sunshine, PID: 641
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prashanth.sunshine/com.example.prashanth.sunshine.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.prashanth.sunshine.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:90)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6062)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-17 11:42:14.846    1437-1437/com.example.prashanth.sunshine I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-17 11:42:15.308    1437-1437/com.example.prashanth.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-17 11:42:15.312    1437-1437/com.example.prashanth.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prashanth.sunshine, PID: 1437
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prashanth.sunshine/com.example.prashanth.sunshine.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.prashanth.sunshine.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:91)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6062)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-17 11:51:54.224    2292-2292/com.example.prashanth.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-17 11:51:54.225    2292-2292/com.example.prashanth.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prashanth.sunshine, PID: 2292
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prashanth.sunshine/com.example.prashanth.sunshine.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.prashanth.sunshine.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:91)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6062)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-17 11:51:56.581    2292-2292/com.example.prashanth.sunshine I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2292 SIG: 9
```

EDIT : Activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what is at line number 90 in MainActivity.java?

Comment: where do you declare this object? mForecastAdapter

Comment: I know the error doesn't reside in activity_main.xml but could you post it here.

Comment: I've declared mForecastAdapter in this line -

   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

Comment: @Prashanth did you try to remove the textview_id in your adapter constructor? If the list_item_forecast.xml just includes the textview there is no need to use the textview_id.

Comment: @TheTanic Yes i tried that, made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I changed certain bits of your code, and it seems to be working. I believe it's the problem with wrong imports of AppCompat library. Below is the entire MainActivity code.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                            .commit();

        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            String[] forecastArray;
            forecastArray = new String[]{
                    "Today - Sunny 88/63",
                    "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                    "Day After - Life",
                    "Kidney",
                    "Saturday",
                    "Sunday"
            };

            List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

            mForecastAdapter = new
                    ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    weekForecast);
            ListView lstview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            lstview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;

        }
    }
}
```

Is this the output you are looking for

[image]

Comment: Yes that is exactly the output i am looking for! But the code that you've pasted still gives me the same "Unfortunately Sunshine has stopped" error. What changes did you make? Thanks!

Comment: Not much. Compare my import statements with yours. I think that is what is causing the issue. Although I'm not sure. I changed getSupportFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager() and some import statements, I believe

Comment: I have all the same imports as yours, still can't get it to run..

If i remove this statement it runs and displays a calendar (why?) - 
      lstview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

Any idea?

Comment: I don't know. But how does it show a calendar?. and what do you mean by a calendar. Try cleaning the project, and rebuilding. Other than that. I'm helpless.

Comment: It displays the calendar for the entire year for some reason with the month and day numbers. I have no idea why it does that. Anyway thanks for your help i'll try cleaning it!